# Find and list items from different lists from a file in python

Tags: python, string, list, find

i want to know how to retrieve multiple items from a list if i give to the program an specific item of the list. This is how my lists looks like:

```
["randomname", "188.xx.xx.xx", "uselessinfo", "2013-09-04 12:03:18"]
["saelyth", "189.xx.xx.xx", "uselessinfoalso", "2013-09-04 12:03:23"]
["randomname2", "121.xxx.xxx.x", "uselessinfoforstackoverflow", "2013-09-04 12:03:25"]
```

This is intended for a chat bot. The first item is the user name, the second one is the IP, and what i need is to find all names associated to the same IP and then print them or send it to chat, this is as far as i did get.

```
if message.body.startswith("!Track"):
  vartogetname = vartogetip = None
  filename = "listas\datosdeusuario.txt"
  for line in open(filename, 'r'):
    retrieved = json.loads(line)
    if retrieved[0] == targettotrack:
      vartogetname = retrieved[0]
      vartogetip = retrieved[1]
      break
      #So far it has opened the file, check my target and get the right IP to track, no issues until here.
  if not vartogetip == None: #So if has found an IP with the target...
    print("Tracking "+targettotrack+": Found "+str(vartogetip)+"...")
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
      retrieved2 = json.loads(line)
      if retrieved2[1] == vartogetip: #If IP is found
        if not retrieved2[0] == targettotrack: #But the name is different...
          print("I found "+retrieved2[0]+" with the same ip") #Did worked, but did several different prints.
#HERE i'm lost, read text and comments after this code.
    sendtochat("I found "+retrieved2[0]+" with the same ip") #Only sent 1 name, not all of them :(
  else:
    sendtochat("IP Not found")
```

Where I said #HERE is where I'd need a code to add items found in the list and add them to another list (I guess?) and then I'd be able to call it in the sendtochat command, however I must be really tired because I can't remember how to do it.

I am working with Python 3.3.2 IDLE and the lists into the file are saved with json and it adds a `\n` at the end for easy reading.

Comment: `if vartogetip is not None:` would be better; one operator and testing for identity instead of equality (`None` is a singleton).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *collect* your matches in a list, then send that *list* of matches to your chatbot:

```
if vartogetip is not None:
    matches = []
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
        ip, name = json.loads(line)[:2]
        if ip == vartogetip and name != targettotrack:
            matches.append(name)

    if matches:  # matches have been found, the list is not empty
        sendtochat("I found {} with the same ip".format(', '.join(matches)))
```

The `', '.join(matches)` call joins the found names together with commas to make for a nicer and more readable format for the names.

Comment: ok... testing... well, that didn't work, but i borrowed the matches.append and merged it with my code with a minus fixes like the (is not None) and now it works perfect. I also learned something new, wich is always fun. Thank you very much, Martijn Pieters :D

Answer (score 0):

**"This is intended for a chat bot. The first item is the user name, the second one is the IP, and what i need is to find all names associated to the same IP and then print them or send it to chat, this is as far as i did get."**

Seems like what you want is a dict which maps IP address strings to a list of usernames associated to that IP address. Maybe try something like this:

```
user_infos = [
["randomname", "188.xx.xx.xx", 'data'],
["saelyth", "189.xx.xx.xx", 'data'],
["randomname2", "121.xxx.xxx.x", 'data'],
["saelyth2", "189.xx.xx.xx", 'data']
]

# Mapping of IP address to a list of usernames :)
ip_dict = {}
# Scan through all the users, assign their usernames to the IP address
for u in user_infos:
    ip_addr = u[1]
    if ip_addr in ip_dict:
        ip_dict[ip_addr].append(u[0])
    else:
        ip_dict[ip_addr] = [u[0]]


# We want to query an IP address "189.xx.xx.xx"
# Let's find all usernames with this IP address
for username in ip_dict["189.xx.xx.xx"]:
    print(username) # Have your chatbot say these names.
```

That will print both 'saelyth' and 'saelyth2' since they have the same IP address.

Comment: Uhm, although i found the answer that i wantd in the previous post, i will also test this one and learn how it works, thanks :D